# problems with output in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I write a script in R using shiny, there I'm using the function `write.table` and `sink()`.

But nothing happens... I don't see the files that should be printed at all.

Here is a part of my script:

```
output$NewDataPlot<-renderPrint({
  DataSets <<- input$newfile
  InputGOI <<- input$newGOI
  sink("config.txt")

  mydata <- na.omit(DataSet) # listwise deletion of missing
  mydata <- scale(mydata) # standardize variables
  library(cluster)
  mydata<-pam(mydata, 10, diss = inherits(mydata, "dist"), metric = "euclidean",
              medoids = NULL, stand = FALSE, cluster.only = TRUE)
  x<-mydata
  mat<-matrix(0,length(x),2)
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    mat[i,1]<<-attributes(x[i])$names
    mat[i,2]<<-x[[i]]
  }
  ##Output PAM clustrring
  write.table(mat, file = paste("foo_clustered_pam",p,".txt", sep=""),
              sep = "\t",col.names = FALSE,row.names = FALSE,quote=FALSE)


  cat(path.expand(DataSets))
  cat("\t")
  cat(paste("foo_clustered_pam",p,".txt", sep=""))
  cat("\n")
  sink()
})
```

this is the short script of ui. it's written in html:

```
      <li>
        <a href="#tab-711-5" data-toggle="tab">New Data Plot</a>
      </li>

      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane" title="NewData" id="tab-711-5">
     <pre id="NewDataPlot" class="shiny-text-output"></pre>
      </div>
```

but the ui here is not necessary. I need that the file will writen (will be output) in the folder that the script is saved.

Comment: Please provide us with a reproducible example. In this case, both the `ui.r` and `server.r`. In addition, don't use global variables `<<-` to make variables available throughout a Shiny app, that is not needed.

Comment: "NewDataPlot" or "NewData" ?..

Comment: NewDataPlot, sorry...